# Where is the "Sleeping in the Elements!" shard?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

In Scribblenauts Unlimited, in the Metaforest stage, there is a shard goal called "Sleeping in the Elements!".  The description is:

> This isn't a comfortable place to sleep!  Create something better for the backpacker!

I've looked everywhere on this stage, with and without the special vision toggled.  Where can I find the backpacker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Kill the bug that is bugging the guy at the bottom, then spawn a bed.

Comment: Yes, the backpacker is the one being bothered by the mosquito.  As for getting the shard, I killed the bug and then spawned the bed and it had no effect.  The bug just keeps respawning after you kill it.  I did finally get it to trigger after placing a mosquito net on the bed.

Answer (score -1):

first you give the camper a net he kills the bugs then if you get out a bed he goes to it and starts to seep on it now you got the sleeping in the elements shard.